# Can an Adobe AIR Application run via the command line output to console?

Tags: command-line, console, air, stdout

I have an AIR application that takes command-line arguments via onInvoke. All is good, but I cannot figure out how to print some status messages back to the user (to stdout / console, so to speak). Is it possible?

Even a default log file for traces would be fine, but I can't find any info about it anywhere. Do I need to create my own log file? Now that'd be silly.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [CommandProxy](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/17/commandproxy-net-air-integration-proof-of-concept/). It is a low level wrapper around your AIR application that lets you send command from AS3 back to the proxy for communicating with the underlying OS. You should be able to add a means of writing to the command line via such a method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible, but I'm not completely sure though.

There is a flashlog.txt file which you can configure so all trace() statements are logged to it. Check this post http://www.digitalflipbook.com/archives/2005/07/trace_from_the.php for more info on how to set it up. This is for logging from the browser, but I'm pretty sure it should also work from an air app.

Additionally, you could use SOS MAX from Powerflasher to log to an external console through an XML socket.

Answer (score 1):

By default, trace() will output to stdout.

Comment: One should not deliver a debug build just to hack a side-effect

Answer (score 1):

Your AIR application is one, big trace window if you want it to be.