# Can you run AIR apps from command line?

Tags: batch-file, air

The question ultimately aims at answering this question: can a batch script run an AIR app? The goal is to setup an AIR app on a web server and make it run through batches. I simply have to know whether this is possible by default or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Oliver Goldman from Adobe [posts how to launch an application from the command line](http://blogs.adobe.com/simplicity/2008/11/how_to_launch_an_air_app_from_the_command_line.html):

> On Windows and Linux, invoking
>   AIR-based applications at the command
>   line is straightforward. On Windows,
>   inside the application's install
>   directory you'll find an executable
>   with the application's name; that's
>   the thing to run from the command
>   line. On Linux, the executable is
>   inside the "bin" subdirectory.
>
> On Mac OS things are slightly
>   trickier. In Finder, applications
>   *appear* to be a single file, but
>   they're really a folder with with an
>   extension of ".app" and a particular
>   interior folder structure. To launch
>   them from the command line with
>   arguments, you have to dig into this
>   structure and find the executable. For
>   example, to launch an application
>   named HelloWorld you'd run:
>
> `/Applications/HelloWorld.app/Contents/MacOS/HelloWorld`

You can also use the [AIR Debug Launcher](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fd7.html). It allows you to launch the application from the command line based on its `application.xml` file without requiring it to be installed.

Comment: Are you able to output to the console from AIR exe?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200860/can-an-adobe-air-application-run-via-the-command-line-output-to-console.